# Automated background image changer

Tags: javascript, image, function, automation, background-image

I've been trying to make an automated background function that changes the background-image of an element after a specified amount of time, but I can't seem to make it work.

So far I've created this:

```
var images["images/1.jpg","images/2.jpg","images/3.jpg","images/4.jpg"]; 

function changeImg() {
   // Change background image of #container element from 1.jpg to 2.jpg
}

function calledEveryHour() {
   setInterval(changeImg(), 1000 * 60 *60);
}
```

If any further information is needed, let me know... I'm not sure how I should do this and what's needed to get it done. I'm stumped and could use some help.
Thank you

Comment: Edited. Don't forget to accept ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
var images = ["images/1.jpg","images/2.jpg","images/3.jpg","images/4.jpg"]; 
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var i = 0;

function changeImg() { 
   if(i>images.length) i = 0;
   var bgImg = new Image();
   bgImg.onload = function(){
      container.style = "background-image:url("+bgImg.src+");";
   }
   bgImg.src = images[i];
   i++;
}

function calledEveryHour() {
   setInterval(changeImg(), 1000 * 60 *60);
}
```

Comment: If you want a fade effect, i could perform this answer, ask for it.

Comment: it says this in the console after I call the "calledEveryHour" function:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'style' of null at Image.bgImg.onload`

Comment: is your source ok ?

Comment: I figured it out, I had the script in the head tag when it should be at the bottom of the body tag. Thank you for your help!